# AutoIt is not working with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I want to search an image in google using Selenium WebDriver.
I have written a AutoIt script to select the image from the drive.
The AutoIt script is not working with chrome, its working fine with Firefox.

Here is my script -

```
WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",5)
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
Sleep(2000)
ControlSetText("File Upload", "", "Edit1", "image.jpg")
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("File Upload", "","Button1");
```

I am not getting any exception in my Java code either.
I have also downloaded AutoIt extension for chrome but it didn't work.
Anyone knows the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try changing the control name to the name Chrome gives it. I believe Chrome recognizes the file upload field as "Open", IE sees it as "Choose File to Upload".

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I put a 2 second wait before executing the AutoIT command and it works now.

I assume that you have compiled your AutoIT script and named the .exe file as Upload. Below is the java code which i have written -

```
Thread.wait(2000);
 String command ="C:\\Users\\Casper\\Desktop\\Resume\\Upload.exe";
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Now question is why i put a 2 second wait before starting the upload and the answer is as soon as you click on the upload button in browser the os control box takes some time to open but in our code we are continuously passing the command and because of it file upload is failing without any Exception. I am just giving the a 2 second time to the java so that the os control window can open and then i am executing my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","C:\Import\assesse-import.csv")
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Update "File upload" with "Open" and compile the AutoIT Script again, it should work fine.